# I have two UITableView in my controller, when I call reloadData() method, it properly works only for one of them

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have two UITableView in my controller, when I call reloadData() method, it properly works only for one of them
I fetch data from firebase, at receiving I set it to array of custom object and call reloadData() but only one looks correct, meanwhile second one is nowhere to be seen.

```swift
FirebaseManager.shared.fetchKebab { kebab in
    self.kebab = kebab
    self.kebabTableView.reloadData()
    self.kebabTableView.snp.updateConstraints { make in
        make.height.equalTo(self.kebabTableView.contentSize.height)
    }
}
        
FirebaseManager.shared.fetchPizza { pizza in
    self.pizza = pizza
    self.pizzaTableView.reloadData()
    
    self.pizzaTableView.snp.updateConstraints { make in
        make.height.equalTo(self.pizzaTableView.contentSize.height)
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if tableView == pizzaTableView {
        return pizza.count
    }
    if tableView == kebabTableView {
        return kebab.count
    }
    return 0
}
    
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if tableView == kebabTableView {
        if let cell = kebabTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MealCell") as? MealCell {
            cell.meal = kebab[indexPath.row]
            cell.setup()
            return cell
        }
    }
    
    if tableView ==  pizzaTableView {
        if let cell = pizzaTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MealCell") as? MealCell {
            cell.meal = pizza[indexPath.row]
            cell.setup()
            return cell
        }
    }
    
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

For second tableView it only calls `numberOfRowsInSection()`

I tried many things and nothing worked for me.

Comment: Try:   DispatchQueue.main.async { self.pizzaTableView.reloadData() }

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: It probably means that the second one isn't visible on screen, so it doesn't call `cellforRowat` and such? What's its frame?

Comment: second one is one the screen, i checked with placeholder, i use snapkit for auto layout

Comment: Have you verified that `numberOfRowsInSection` is returning a non-zero result?

Comment: this method is working, and yes, its return non-zero result

Comment: Did you checked that the MealCell is registered for second table view ?

Comment: yes, I did......

Comment: Consider posting a sample project which reproduces the issue then.